# How to check if any of the entries in each column of my dataframe is a number?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am impressed by using a simple code that enables me to check if there is an entry of my DataFrame that contains integer or a float in my the columns

Consider the following DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
index =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
dct =  {'Region': {0: 'Amma', 1: 'Amma', 2: 'Amma', 3: np.nan, 4: 'Amma', 5: 'Amma', 6: 'Amma', 7: '1', 8: 'Amma', 9: 'Amma', 10: 'Amma', 11: 'Amma', 12: 'Amma', 13: 'Amma', 14: 'Amma', 15: 'Amma', 16: 'Amma', 17: 'Amma', 18: 'Amma', 19: 'Amma', 20: 'Amma', 21: 'Amma', 22: 'Amma', 23: 'Amma', 24: 'Amma', 25: 'Amma', 26: 'Amma', 27: 'Amma', 28: 'Amma', 29: 'Amma', 30: 'Amma', 31: 'Amma', 32: 'Amma', 33: 'Amma', 34: 'Amma', 35: 'Amma', 36: 'Amma', 37: 'Amma', 38: 'Amma', 39: 'Amma'}, 'Urban/Rural residence': {0: 'Urba', 1: 'Urba', 2: 'Urba', 3: 'Urba', 4: 'Urba', 5: 'Urba', 6: 'Urba', 7: 'Urba', 8: 'Urba', 9: 'Urba', 10: 'Urba', 11: 'Urba', 12: 'Urba', 13: 'Urba', 14: 'Urba', 15: 'Urba', 16: 'Urba', 17: 'Urba', 18: 'Urba', 19: 'Urba', 20: 'Urba', 21: 'Urba', 22: 'Urba', 23: 'Rural', 24: 'Urba', 25: 'Urba', 26: 'Urba', 27: 'Urba', 28: 'Urba', 29: 'Urba', 30: 'Urba', 31: 'Urba', 32: 'Urba', 33: 'Urba', 34: '1.65', 35: 'Urba', 36: 'Urba', 37: 'Urba', 38: 'Urba', 39: 'Urba'}}
new_df = pd.DataFrame( dct, index=index )
```

Now also I had to define some functions as

```
def solve(lis):                                        
    for x in lis:
        try:
            yield float(x)
        except ValueError:    
            pass

def CheckIfFloat(new_df):
    a=[]
    for i in new_df.columns:
        new_df1=new_df[new_df[i].isna()==0][i]
        A=list(solve(new_df1))
        if len(A)!=0:
            a.insert(len(a),i)
        return a
```

Now for some reason, this did not work as expected, the outcome should be both columns. But here it only gives the first column.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_numeric` with argument `errors='coerce'` and create a list comprehension of any column that contains any valid number.

```
number_cols = new_df.columns[[pd.to_numeric(new_df[col], errors='coerce').notna().any() for col in new_df]]
```

And you can index by

```
new_df[number_cols]
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `Series` with columns names and boolean for check if at least one numeric value by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'` parameter - it return `NaN`s for non numeric, so test values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html).

If need select columns use[`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = new_df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce').notna().any())

print (mask)
Region                   True
Urban/Rural residence    True
dtype: bool

df = new_df.loc[:, mask]
```

If need columns names:

```
cols = mask.index[mask].tolist()
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
def CheckIfFloat(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:    
        return False

mask = new_df.applymap(CheckIfFloat).any()
```